# I have 3 variables which will return true or false values and i need to compare those 3 variables i need to return values i have tried below code

Tags: javascript, function, variables, comparison-operators

but this code is working only all the three variables are true please suggest for other conditions it is not working.

i would like to know how all the below condition executes.

```
  //this is the function//
 function()
    {
      if({{var - customJS - page_type_lookup}} === 'product' || {{var - aev - element click text}} === 'Quick View') {
        var A = document.querySelector('#pdpMain > div.product-aplus-content.clearfix > div.content-desktop > div.content-container > img').getAttribute('alt').includes('A Plus Content');// variable 1
     
        var B = document.querySelector("#rta-badge > div.rta-assembly-content > div.rta-left-section > span").innerText.includes('Assembly required');// variable 2
    
        var C = document.querySelector('#product-content > div.product-variations.clearfix > div.attribute.variant-dropdown > div.attribute-values-section > div.label.va-navSectionalOrientation').innerText.includes('Sectional Orientation');// variable 3
        
    //comparison    // if(A === true && B === true && C === true)
        {
          return 'A+ Content, RTA, Sectional configurator';
        }
        else if(A === true && B === true && C !== true)
        {
          return 'A+ Content, RTA';
        }
       else if(A === true && B !== true && C === true)
       {
         return 'A+ Content, Sectional configurator';
       }
        else if (A !== true && B === true && C === true)
        {
          return 'RTA, Sectional configurator';
        }
        else if(A === true && B !== true && C !== true)
        {
          return 'A+ content';
         }
        else if(A !== true && B === true && C !== true)
        {
          return 'RTA';
        }
        else if(A !== true && B !== true && C === true)
        {
          return 'Sectional configurator';
        }
        else if(A !== true && B !== true && C !== true)
        {
          return;
        }
      }

}
```

Comment: Could you describe your intent? The logical errors are not clear if you do not state in plain words what it is that you want the desired behavior to be.

Answer (score 2):

f.e.:

```
var arr = [];
if (A) arr.push("A+ content");
if (B) arr.push("RTA");
if (C) arr.push("Sectional configurator");

return arr.join(", ");
```

Ok, here is an example:

```js
function go () {
  var arr = [];
  if (document.getElementById("A").checked) arr.push("A+ Content");
  if (document.getElementById("B").checked) arr.push("RTA");
  if (document.getElementById("C").checked) arr.push("Sectional configurator");
  document.getElementById("ret").value = arr.join(", ");
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="A">variable A</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="B">variable B</input><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="C">variable C</input><br>
<button onclick="javascript:go();">Go!</button><br>
<textarea id="ret"></textarea>
```

Comment: the above code is working only when all three variables are true if only one or two variables are true it is not working.

Comment: please suggest thanks

Comment: Hi, it is possible, that I do not understand your assignment… I believe you want to return a string, where are "named" properties, that are true. So if A is true, there should be "A+ content", etc. in any combination. The code above adds that "valid" "names" to an array. An array to string joined by comma is returned.

Comment: thank yo so much michel now it is working fine